# How could I make an app login in a website and get info in the background?

Tags: ios

I think I am mostly struggling with this problem because I do not know what to search for.
I want to make an app that allows the user to enter their gift card number and use that number to login to this website:

https://www.getmybalance.com

I have no idea how to do this without control over the website. Is it even possible to do so?
I don't want to use a UIWebView to show the page.

Comment: That is going to be hard if the website doesn't have an open API.

Comment: wouldn't there be a way to redesign the interface by myself but keep their "logic"?

Comment: Not if you want to avoid using a WebView like your question states. The other answers talk about getting data back via POST. This would be the API you need to scrape from the URL or get from the provider.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on NSURLConnection, you're going to have to execute a post request to login. Then you're going to have to determine whether or not you logged in successfully probably by parsing the returned page.  NSURLConnection will handle storing the login cookie the site returns. After you've logged in you're probably going to need to execute another post request to query their system.  Once again you will have to probably parse the result out of the HTML page that is returned.

NSURLConnection:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSURLConnection Delegate Protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate

This all of course assumes that this website doesn't have an API you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to programatically POST in https to the server, then you will get back some DOM document, or JSON, or some weird thing,  which you then parse.

POSTing with iOS is pretty easy, look at something like LRResty https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRResty or similar.

When you get the data back, first thing to do is look at it with NSLog. Then if the data is HTML, you will need to wade into the HTML to get the result.

The problem with that approach is that the company hosting the page may change their API at any time. You should ask them to either not ever change anything (if they want to change, then make a new page and leave the old one working, or better, support a simple REST API - which would also help them build nice AJAX/html5 web sites in the future.).